# How to grant Lambda access to ElasticSearch in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am successfully accessing the AWS ElasticSearch service with my local AWS credentials. However when trying from lambda, I get the following:

> User:
>   arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/dudeman-workouts-dev-graphqlLambdaServiceRoleXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX/dudeman-workouts-dev-graphqlLambdaXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX
>   is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost

This has me confused since the role that the lambda assumes has the following inline policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "es:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:domain/general-elasticsearch",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's the policy on the cluster itself:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:root"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXX:domain/general-elasticsearch/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

The policy simulator says all is good:

[image]

Comment: What does the policy on the ES cluster look like?

Comment: @jordanm added to the bottom of the question. I went to the domain > Actions > Modify access policy. I hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Try to run the role through https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/ , it's not end-all-be-all, but can rule out some obvious gotchas

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha thanx, I attached the results.

Comment: This might be a result of SCP (AWS Organizations policy), if your account is in organization, check that

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha sorry, I made a mistake earlier(didn't provide ES domain as resource), now the simulator passes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `/*` to the end of the resource in the IAM policy.

IIRC, Elasticsearch policies behave similarly to S3 policies: if you omit the trailing `/*` you can only invoke requests that affect the cluster as a whole. The various HTTP requests, however, affect things like `https://cluster/index`.